# How to position an absolute div next to an element in a scrollable section, but outside the section

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable div that consists of several divs, laid out like list items:

```
  <div class="scrollbox">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">
      item 2
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
    <div class="item">item 4</div>
    <div class="item">item 5</div>
    <div class="item">item 6</div>
  </div>
```

I want to position a div (`box`) to the left of one of these list items, but outside of the scrollable section. It should be "anchored" to the list item, i.e. it should scroll with the item and disappear when the item is out of view. Here is the CSS:

```
.scrollbox {
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: magenta;
}

.box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 4px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jshamash/b7csz3z6/

Notice how the `box` div does not show up. It is outside the scrollable section, so it gets hidden. Adding `overflow-x: visible` doesn't change this, either.

Here is my attempt at a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jshamash/Lfshojh5/
which I don't like because it's hacky, and requires even more hacky stuff to make the bottom border show up.

Comment: If the little `div` is supposed to be anchored to a specific item, and it should only show when the item is in the scroll view, why does it need to be outside the scroll window? Seems like you could just place it inside the scroll window and all your problems would be solved.

Comment: I want to keep the border on the scroll view though, and I want this element to be outside the border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I played around with this for a bit and found a very hacky solution that works. JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jshamash/n41yabt8/

```css
/*
$height: 100px;
$width: 150px;
$scroll-width: 15px;
$border-width: 1px;
$box-width: 10px;
*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.scrollbox-wrapper {
  width: calc(150px - 15px);
  height: calc(100px + 2px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

.scrollbox {
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(100% + 10px + 15px + 1px);
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  position: absolute;
}

.inner {
  width: calc(100% - 10px - 15px - 1px);
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}

.item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: magenta;
}

.box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollbox-wrapper">
  <div class="scrollbox">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="item">item 1</div>
      <div class="item">
        item 2
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">item 3</div>
      <div class="item">item 4</div>
      <div class="item">item 5</div>
      <div class="item">item 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```